# bootstrap mobile menu stays open in my header.html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a separate html file for the header.
so my index, where I also have put all the necessary link to work with bootstrap, looks like this:

```
<head>
...
<link
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css "/>

</head>

<body>

<header>
                <script>
                    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
                        fetch('header.html')
                            .then(response => response.text())
                            .then(data => {
                                document
                                    .querySelector('header')
                                    .innerHTML = data;
                            })
                    })
                </script>
            </header>

.....


script
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-BBtl+eGJRgqQAUMxJ7pMwbEyER4l1g+O15P+16Ep7Q9Q+zqX6gSbd85u4mG4QzX+"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
```

and this is my header.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://">Lorem Ipsum</a>
        <button
            class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
            aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <!-- <i class="bi bi-list"></i> -->
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="./#about-us">about</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="./#services">services</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="./#team">team</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="./#contacts">contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

So I can open the menu by clicking the burger icon, but if I click it again it stays open.
Does the fact that the navbar is in a separate file cause the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, navbar being in a separate file is not a problem.

The problem is that in index.html, you're loading Bootstrap twice, so apparently there is some conflict.

Just load Bootstrap once, and the one in the first script tag, because that one already includes Popper, which you're loading in lower, second script tags.

So, change your index.html like this:

```
<head>
...
<link
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css "/>

</head>

<body>

<header>
                <script>
                    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
                        fetch('header.html')
                            .then(response => response.text())
                            .then(data => {
                                document
                                    .querySelector('header')
                                    .innerHTML = data;
                            })
                    })
                </script>
            </header>

.....


<-- removed scripts from here -->

</body>
```

Simulations:

- BS loaded twice: not working

```html
<head>
...
<link
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css "/>

</head>

<body>

<header>
                <script>
                    const data = ` <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg"> <div class="container-fluid"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://">Lorem Ipsum</a> <button class="navbar-toggler"type="button"data-bs-toggle="collapse"data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown"aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"aria-expanded="false"aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <!-- <i class="bi bi-list"></i> --> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button> <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown"> <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto"> <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="./#about-us">about</a> </li> <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="./#services">services</a> </li> <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="./#team">team</a> </li> <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="./#contacts">contact</a> </li> </ul> </div> </div> </nav> `;
                    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
                        setTimeout(()=>{
                                document
                                    .querySelector('header')
                                    .innerHTML = data;
                            }, 1000);
                    })
                </script>
            </header>

.....


<script
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-BBtl+eGJRgqQAUMxJ7pMwbEyER4l1g+O15P+16Ep7Q9Q+zqX6gSbd85u4mG4QzX+"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
```

- BS loaded once: working

```html
<head>
...
<link
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css "/>

</head>

<body>

<header>
                <script>
                    const data = ` <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg"> <div class="container-fluid"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://">Lorem Ipsum</a> <button class="navbar-toggler"type="button"data-bs-toggle="collapse"data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown"aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"aria-expanded="false"aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <!-- <i class="bi bi-list"></i> --> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button> <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown"> <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto"> <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="./#about-us">about</a> </li> <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="./#services">services</a> </li> <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="./#team">team</a> </li> <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="./#contacts">contact</a> </li> </ul> </div> </div> </nav> `;
                    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
                        setTimeout(()=>{
                                document
                                    .querySelector('header')
                                    .innerHTML = data;
                            }, 1000);
                    })
                </script>
            </header>

.....




</body>
```

Comment: It works like a charm now, thank you. I also changed the hierarchy by putting bootstrap before a cookie banner script (provided by the service). So now I have: Google analytics scripts, bootstrap and than cookie banner scripts

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be when the menu is toggled, it has some `span` overlay on it, so when you click, you click on the overlay, not the button.

You can open the Devtools on Chrome by right-click and choose `Inspect element` to check. Or you can try find the error by checking the `console.log()` if it return any errors